# FCM push notification don't pop up Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications. When a message is received while the application is in the background and terminated, the notification does not appear as a popup but rather displays in the status bar.

```
  {
  "message":{
    "topic":"subscriber-updates",
    "notification":{
      "body" : "This week's edition is now available.",
      "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
    },
    "data" : {
      "volume" : "3.21.15",
      "contents" : "http://www.news-magazine.com/world-week/21659772"
    },
    "android":{
      "priority":"high"
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-priority":"5"
      }
    },
    "webpush": {
      "headers": {
        "Urgency": "high"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I set priority as shown on the documentation bud it doesn't work.
Any help is appreciated